# How to detemine the message is sent on behalf of or sent as other mailbox via exchange tracking logs

Tags: exchange

Has any properties within exchange tracking log can be used to determined the message is sent on behalf of and sent as other mailbox and determined the exactly delegated mailbox？

Answer (score 0):

We may get those information by comparing the property of "PurportedSender", "Sender" and "Return Path".
[image]

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful.